# How do I do a SQL query that finds numbers in a field that is only 6 characters long and starts with the number 5?

Tags: sql

See the following code:

```
select no_
from dbo.customer
where no_ like '5%%%%%'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
select no_ from dbo.customer where no_ like '5_____'
```

[LIKE operator](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) recognizes two wildcard characters :

- % - The percent sign represents zero, one, or multiple characters
- _ - The underscore represents a single character

Comment: Perfect!  I searched every phrase I could think of, including my question above, to no avail.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you would do:

```
 select no_ from dbo.customer where no_ like '5%'
```

`%` is a wildcard that matches any number of characters, including none.

If you want to guarantee exactly 6 characters as well:

```
 select no_ from dbo.customer where no_ like '5_____'
```

`_` is a wildcard that matches exactly one character.

Answer (score 0):

i would also add isnumeric

```
select no_ from dbo.customer where no_ like '5_____' and ISNUMERIC(no_) = 1
```